# Horizontal Name Sort I cant figure out why it not sorting my line into alphabetical order

Tags: java, arraylist

// Enter Harry,Sue,Mary,Bruce should print out like Bruce,Harry,Mary,Sue
//but I'm only getting it printed out again it hasn't been sorted unsure why?
//Please help

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
/**
 * Exercise 31
 * Horizontal Name Sort
 * @author (Luke Dolamore)
 * @version (5/04/17)
 */
public class Exercise31 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Input (end with #)");
        String input = kb.nextLine();
        while ( ! input.equals("#") ) {
            processName(input);
            input = kb.nextLine();
        }    
    } //main
    public static void processName (String line) {
        Scanner scn = new Scanner(line);
        ArrayList<String> name = new ArrayList<String>();  
        while ( scn.hasNext() ) {
            line = scn.next();
            scn.useDelimiter(",");
            name.add(line);
            Collections.sort(name); 
        }
        for ( String nam : name ) {

            System.out.println(nam);
        }
    }
} // class Exercise31
```

Comment: call Collections.sort(name); after you are done reading all the inputs from the string. no sense in sorting it as you parse. Put it outside your while and before you print the names.

Comment: Yea im abit stuck need to go see the teacher

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already know that the names will be comma seperated in the line passed to processName you should just use the split method like so

```
public static void processName (String line) {
    ArrayList<String> name = new ArrayList<String>();
    //splits the string around commas
    String[] inputs = line.split(",");
    //now take all the names/values that were seperated by the comma and add them to your list
    for(int i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++)
    {
        name.add(inputs[i]);
    }
    //sort the list once
    Collections.sort(name);
    //output the names/values in sorted order
    for ( String nam : name ) {

        System.out.println(nam);
    }
}
```

Or define the delimeter outside the while instead of inside

```
public static void processName (String line) {
    Scanner scn = new Scanner(line);
    scn.useDelimiter(","); //declare it here
    ArrayList<String> name = new ArrayList<String>();  
    while ( scn.hasNext() ) {
        line = scn.next();
        name.add(line);
    }

    Collections.sort(name);

    for ( String nam : name ) {

        System.out.println(nam);
    }
}
```

Example Run 1

```
Input (end with #)
bruce,harry,mary,sue
bruce
harry
mary
sue
#
```

Example Run 2

```
Input (end with #)
z,x,y,r,g,q,a,b,c
a
b
c
g
q
r
x
y
z
```

Comment: you were so close in your original implementation i posted the fixed original. you just had to declare the delimiter above your while instead of inside

Answer (score 1):

Looking at it, the minimal change to get it to work would be to move the `scn.useDelimiter` call before the while loop.

As this is a homework question, I'll leave you with the hint that there are a few more things that are not necessarily in the right place. However I don't think they influence the end result.

Comment: Thanks for the feeback